# "a number from range [0, 10]" vs. "a number from the range [0, 10]"

Tags: articles, definite-article

Do we need any article before "range":

> a number from range [0, 10]
>
> a number from the range [0, 10]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes - you are introducing and specifying a new noun-object (range), so use of the definite article is correct.

Comment: Thank you! As far as I'm aware we English speakers say "number 5", not "the number 5". Why should we say "the range [0, 10]" then?

Also "This proves theorem 1.3", not "This proves the theorem 1.3"

Comment: Well, it's not quite that clear cut. If you are taking the number itself as the topic, you'd use "the". For example, "let's test whether the number 497 is prime..." If you are using the number to refer to something else, though, then you typically won't use the article. "Can you pass me box number 8, please?" or, as you say, "This proves theorem 1.3"